# Is there are any way to make browsermob-proxy serve HTTPS request?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I use Selenium's ChromeDriver in order to test loading time with certain js file. And for that I used `browsermob-proxy` python server. Approach is

1. Start proxy server
2. Block certain website via `blacklist` function.
3. Open Chrome driver with an argument `proxy-server`

   `chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

   proxy_url = urlparse(Crawler.proxy.proxy).path

   chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy_url)

   Crawler.proxy.blacklist(".*my-js-lays-here.*", 200)

   Crawler.driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, chrome_options=chrome_options)`

Problem is that my proxy can't handle HTTPS requests and this results in forever loading website. I searched all the way throught `browsermob-proxy` documentation, but didn't find any code example on how to handle https requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try to accept the certs and if it still doesn't work change your proxy server settings

```
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities

...

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,
    desired_capabilities=capabilities,
    executable_path=config.CHROME_PATH)
```